# sending object in express results in an empty object

Tags: node.js, express

Here is the post login method of the user router, it finds a user, generates a token and returns an object containing said user and token. It also console.log the user so I'm sure it's loaded.

```
router.post("/user/login", async (request, response) => {
try{

    const user = await User.findByCredentials(request.body.email, request.body.password)
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
    console.log(user)
    response.json({
        user: user,
        token
    })
}catch(error){
    console.log(error)
    response.status(400).send()
}
})
```

This is the user model which i learned to make through a Udemy course by Andrew Mead.

```
const validator = require("validator")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

const Housekeeping = require("./housekeeping")

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
},
surname:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
},
role:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate(value){
        if(value < 6){
            throw new Error("Password must be at least 6 characters long.")
        }

        if(value.toLowerCase().includes("password")){
            throw new Error("Password can\'t contain \"password\".")
        }
    }
},
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate(value){
        if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
            throw new Error("Email is invalid.")
        }
    }
},
tokens: [{
    token:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}]
},{
timestamps: true
})
//Reference fields
userSchema.virtual("housekeepings", {
ref: "Housekeeping",
localField: "_id",
foreignField: "user"
})

//Custom schema methods
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function(){
const user = this

const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toString()}, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({token})
await user.save()

return token
}

userSchema.methods.toJSON = async function(){
const user = this
const userObject = user.toObject()

delete userObject.password
delete userObject.tokens

return userObject
}

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
const user = await User.findOne({email})

if(!user){
    throw new Error("Unable to login.")
}

const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

if(!isMatch){
    throw new Error("Unable to login")
}

return user
}

//Middleware
userSchema.pre("save", async function(next){
const user = this

if(user.isModified("password")){
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
}

next()
})

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

The console.log shows the user object as expected but the result on the other side is an empty object ("user":{})

I use Postman to verify

[image: Postman response]

I use the following software:

- OS:      RHEL8 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8)
- IDE:     Visual Studio Code V1.58
- Node.js: V10.24.0
- Express: V6.14.11

Comment: Have you tried with ```response.json({user, token})``` instead of ```response.send(...)```? The ```res.send(...)``` function sets the content type to text/Html which means that the client will now treat it as text. It then returns the response to the client. The ```res.json(...)``` function on the other handsets the content-type header to application/JSON so that the client treats the response string as a valid JSON object. It also then returns the response to the client.

Comment: Hello Carlo, I've tried your suggestion with no success but, thank you for trying :)

Comment: Can you add more information to have a better view of the problem

Comment: Did you get token also empty at the other side ?

Comment: @Rajatkashyap No the token does get transferred correctly.

Comment: @L.Blommers Before ```response.send(...)``` can you print to the console both ```user``` and ```token```. The result is correct or do you expect something different?

Comment: @CarloCorradini The console.log gives the correct output for both user and token

Comment: Strange. Try ```response.json({ user, token }).end();```

Comment: @CarloCorradini Still the same result

Comment: Try: ```response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json').send(JSON.stringify({ user, token }));```. However, this should be automatically done by express using .json.

Comment: @CarloCorradini this results in "TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Comment: ```response.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');``` and then ```response.send(JSON.stringify({ user, token }));```

Comment: @CarloCorradini Still an empty object

Comment: Mumble, mumble, mumble... Can you share the code???

Comment: Please tell us exactly how you know the user object is empty. It's possible something is wrong in the requester. And do use `res.json()` if your requester expects JSON.

Comment: Is there any other middleware that can possibly alter whatever comes out of your method? In other words, does the issue persist in a stripped down application that consists of only this particular route?

Comment: As other said, this is super strange. @WiktorZychla have a good point. Retry only with a simple post truscture without anything else. Pure and simple. Let us know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `async` keyword causes the problem in the following line in user schema:

```
userSchema.methods.toJSON = async function(){
```

So removing the async may solve the problem.

The reason can be the same issue with this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/517) in github.